# Show custom image on google map marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, google-maps-markers, networkonmainthread

I am working on Google map in an Android app.  I need to create a map marker with a custom image.  I can parse the input to get a list of images, but can't figure out how to load one image into the marker object.  I want to use asynchronous tasks to avoid exceptions in the network or main thread.

I've researched many links, but they are setting the image with a drawable.
The result would be something like this:

[[image: some thing like this]

Comment: Improved wording; fixed grammar.

Answer (score 1):

From Google [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image)

```
private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
  private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(MELBOURNE)
                            .title("Melbourne")
                            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```